# How to find Max/Min from a common column across multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, statistics

As the titles states, I'm trying to find the global max/min of a specific column that is found across every dataframe. I've been trying to use a for loop but am having a hard time iterating on my sequential file name structure.

```
fileCount <- NROW(filenames)

finalmin = Inf
finalmax = -Inf

for(i in 1:fileCount){

    testmin <- min(dframe[i]$Receiving)
    testmax <- max(dframe[i]$Receiving)

    if(testmin < finalmin){ finalmin <- testmin}
    if(testmax > finalmax) finalmax <- testmax
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `rbind`/`rbindlist` your df's together, then get the maximum of the column..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose you have the following dataframes

```
  d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,20,3), y2=c(4,5,6))
  d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1), y2=c(6,5,4))
  d3 <- data.frame(y1=c(6,5,4), y2=c(3,2,1))
  d4 <- data.frame(y1=c(9,91,9), y2=c(8,8,8))

  //Creates a list with all your dataframes, does not matter how many. 
  dfs <- Filter(function(x) is(x, "data.frame"), mget(ls()))

   z1<-0

  for(i in 1:length(dfs)){
   z<-max(dfs[[i]]$y1)
   if(z>z1){
   z1<-z
   }
   }

   print(z1)
```

Comment: My code won't have the same amount of dataframes every-time it is used. The " fileCount <- NROW(filenames) " line is used to know how how many there are and they are named sequentially (dframe1, dframe2, dframe3....). I don't know how I would create a list of them all.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not entirely sure how Filter() works but I was able to adapt your code to solve my problem.